# angularjs: ng-include has problems with ng-form on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML element like this

```
<section ng-include src="'/views/barfoo.html'" ng-form="myForm"/>
```

When running this code I get the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'form', required by directive 'form', can't be found!
```

Now I found a solution, like this

```
<section  ng-form="myForm">
    <div ng-include src="'/views/barfoo.html'"/>
</section>
```

However, I would like to know why my first attempt doesn't work and if it can be fixed ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/JY9Bs/)). It is probably elsewhere.

Comment: You're right. Thnx for pointing out!

Comment: I'm experiencing the described behaviour with 1.2.0-rc2; while it doesn't happen with 1.2.0rc1